# Error Tag Not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

Error of any type like:

1. Variable use but not declare.
2. Extends interface but not implement method.
3. Missing semicolon. etc.

It is not showing in android studio untill I have run project. Any type of error does not show even syntax error.

Comment: what is your problem? paste some code here and explain.

Comment: make sure your root package is correct. bcz without correct root package compiler will not work. com.etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

Goto file menu and click **Invalidate Caches/Restart...**

If it still does not work you need to check whether **Code Inspection** is enabled (also in file menu).

You can also goto file menu Settings -> Code Style -> Inspections and check whether inspections are enabled.

Comment: @DheerajBansal Does gradle sync?

Comment: suppose I miss semicolon then It does not show error after run project I see error.

Comment: start a new project or any other project in same android studio and then check for the same. If issue came up means your settings are changed, if not then it means there is error with your R file

Comment: @AnkushBist  I tried creating another project but even that is giving me this issue i.e no inline errors. Can you help I have tried all the solutions available on the interner.

Comment: @RajeshK do check your XML file. Or put your question with code error and image for more detail information show other developers can check and guide you.

Comment: @AnkushBist Thank You very much for replying. This issue was with all the files/classes. Solved it by solving by reinstalling Android Studio.